# (Harris Corner Detector) How to write this in equation (using only numpy)

Tags: python, numpy

This is my code (have 4 sections, this one is the find_corner section):

```
padded_size = window_size//2
padded_image = np.pad(image, padded_size, 'edge')
Ix, Iy = partial_derivative(padded_image)
Ixx = Ix**2
Ixy = Iy*Ix
Iyy = Iy**2
    
height, width = image.shape
output = np.zeros(image.shape)
    
for y in range(output.shape[0]):
    for x in range(output.shape[1]):
        m = np.array([[Ixx[y,x],Ixy[y,x]],[Ixy[y,x],Iyy[y,x]]])
        output[y,x] = np.linalg.det(m) - k*(np.trace(m)**2)

return output
```

I think my code is wrong at variable m
because it must be the summation of Ixx,Ixy,Iyy
according to this [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXwIC.png) but I don't know how to write that as equation
please help me.

Comment: I have not checked the loop, but I think that `Ixy = Iy*Ix` should not be element-wise but a dot product (`np.dot(Ix*Iy)`), and I'd say the same for `Ixx` and `Iyy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try this.

```
height, width = image.shape
output = np.zeros(image.shape)
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        Sxx = np.sum(Ixx[y:y+window_size, x:x+window_size])
        Sxy = np.sum(Ixy[y:y+window_size, x:x+window_size])
        Syy = np.sum(Iyy[y:y+window_size, x:x+window_size])
        M = np.array([[Sxx,Sxy],[Sxy,Syy]])
        det=np.linalg.det(M)
        trace=np.matrix.trace(M)
        R=det-k*(trace**2)
        output[y, x] = R

return output
```